# In AngularJS, can you chain attribute directive events with a different defined order for each element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

On a given HTML element can you define the order that directives are chained in without hardcoding `priority` in the directive to allow independent directive chaining?

Example:

Let's say for a given element click, we want to

1. Check if the user is authenticated
2. Log an action
3. Load data
4. Submit the form.

However, steps 1-4 all are single-responsibility and have no knowledge of each other. Step 4, in general, does not rely on steps 1-3, so the following are all valid buttons:

```
<button check-user-is-authenticated log-some-action load-new-data submit-form></button>
<button submit-form log-some-action></button> 
<button check-user-is-authenticated submit-form></button>
```

However, the individual buttons do know the order the directives are supposed to run in: for `<button submit-form log-some-action></button>`, we want to submit the form then log the data.

Example of the checkUserIsAuthenticated directive. Other directives are similar.

```
MyApp.directive('checkUserIsAuthenticated', ['app', (app) ->
  {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: ( scope, element, attrs ) ->
      element.bind( "click", (event) ->
        if(app.authenticated)
          #continue running directives
          true
        else
          #Go and authenticate then continue with any other directives
          app.goAuthenticate()
      )
  }
])
```

**Most directives do not rely on the current controller/scope, so using the controllers to handle this will add a lot of code duplication throughout the many controllers in the app.**

Comment: You are binding procedural logic to the HTML and I think this is not the best way to go. I would bet that there is no straightforward solution to this problem for this reason: it is not meant to work this way. It would probably be better to expose the logic of the procedural directives as services and call them from e.g. a dedicated controller per button.

Comment: Each directive links to it's own service/controller, but the overall button-specific single controllers aren't a sensible option. Let's say there are 10 different pages with their own controllers that open the camera. Adding `<button log-data open-camera data-to-log="button_id_513">` with two separate services is easier to maintain than having to create dependencies and handling them in each controller.

Answer (score 0):

just one way to solve your problem:

write a directive that handles the click event and calls the provided service methods:

```
<button chained-actions="a:b:c">Action a b c</button>
```

modul defintion:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.factory('a', function($http){
  return function(){
    console.log('A');
  }
})

.factory('b', function($http){
  return function(){
    console.log('B');
  }
})

.factory('c', function($http){
  return function(){
    console.log('C');
  }
})

.directive('chainedActions', function($injector){
  return function($scope, $element, $attr){
      $element.on('click', function(){
         $scope.$apply(function(){
         var actions = $attr.chainedActions.split(':')
         angular.forEach(actions, function(action){
             var actionServie = $injector.get(action);
             actionServie();
         });
      });
    });
  };
})
;
```

here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jpRIAhZWHrEBcN2mBieb?p=info